# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.site.ru/category/#atlas

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cms

Есть скрипт, который отдельно хорошо работает, но когда я его вставляю в запись в Word-Press, то выдает следующую ошибку
`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://www.site.ru/category/#atlas`

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var j=jQuery.noConflict();
 j(document).ready(function() {
  if (j('.block-color').length > 0) {
   j('.block-color').each(function() {
    var ithis = j(this);
    var active = ithis.find('.color_thumb.active');
    if (active.length > 0) {
     ithis.css('background-image', 'url(' + active.attr('href') + ')');
     ithis.find('.color_code span').text(active.data('code'));
     if (active.data('width')) {
      ithis.find('.color_code em').text(active.data('width'));
      ithis.find('.color_code b').text(active.data('sostav'));
     }
    }
   });
  }
  
  j('.color_thumb').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var ithis = j(this);
   var block = ithis.parents('.block-color');
   block.css('background-image', 'none');
   block.css('background-image', 'url(' + ithis.attr('href') + ')');
   block.find('.color_code span').text(ithis.data('code'));
   if (ithis.data('width')) {
    ithis.find('.color_code em').text(ithis.data('width'));
    ithis.find('.color_code b').text(ithis.data('sostav'));
   }
   block.find('.color_thumb').removeClass('active');
   ithis.addClass('active');
  });
 
  j('.page_nav a:not(.ex_link), .target_link').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var ithis = j(this);
   j('html,body').animate({'scrollTop': j(ithis.attr('href')).offset().top}, 600, function() {
    window.location.hash = ithis.attr('href');
   });
  });
 
  j('.color_tab_links a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var ithis = j(this);
   j('.color_tab_links a').removeClass('active');
   ithis.addClass('active');
   j('.color_tab').hide();
   j(ithis.attr('href')).fadeIn();
  });
 
  j('.next_collection').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (j('.color_tab_links a.active').next('a').length > 0) {
    j('.color_tab_links a.active').next('a').trigger('click');
   } else {
    j('.color_tab_links a').eq(0).trigger('click');
   }
  });
 
  j('.work_gal_thumb a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   j('.work_gal_thumb a').removeClass('active');
   j(this).addClass('active');
   j('.work_gal img').hide().attr('src', j(this).attr('href')).load(function() {
    j(this).fadeIn();
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<div id='colors' class='block block-rollshtory_colors'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='h2'>Цвета и коллекции</div>
        <div class='color_tab_links'>
         <a href='#atlas'><span>Атлас</span></a>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div class='color_tabs'>
     <div id='atlas' class='color_tab' style='display: none;'>
      <div class='block block-color' style="background-image: url('/atlas/TR_0003.jpg');">
       <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='color_code'>
         <div>
          Код цвета
          <span>03</span>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class='color_block_overlay'>
         <div class='color_block_overlay__title h4'>Выберите цвет</div>
         <div class='color_thumbs'>
          <a class='color_thumb active' data-sostav='100% полиэстэр' data-width='2 м.' data-code='03' href='/atlas/TR_0003.jpg'>
           <img width='53' height='27' title='Рольшторы' alt='Рольшторы' src='/atlas/TR_0003_thumb.jpg'>
          </a>
         </div>
         <a class='dotted_link next_collection' href='#'>Следующая коллекция</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Поясните как вы этот скрипт вставляете в запись

Comment: вот таким текстом. Редактировать запись, там вкладка HTML и туда